# css change background color of inner div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a anchor tag, inside that one `<div>` and on that i have 3 `<span>` tag, on the hover of that `<a>` tag, how can i change the `<div>` background color and font color?

This is my : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4rf3pmva/2/)

Below is my code.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="col-xs-12 no-padding">
    <img src="../images/1.jpg" class="img-responsive width_100">
    <div class="imgContent">
        <span class="imgContentHeaderArticle">NEWS</span>
        <span class="imgContentHeaderComment">22 COMMENTS</span>
        <span class="imgContentMainFooter text-bold">Porous Innovation: Innovating within amorphous organization boundaries</span>
    </div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.imgContent{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0px;
  background: rgba(10, 75, 221, 0.25) !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.imgContentHeaderArticle{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
}
.imgContentHeaderComment
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 5px;
}
.imgContentMainFooter{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

ON hover on anchor tag i want to change that blue color to yellow and that font color to Dark blue

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by doing something similar to this:

```
.no-padding:hover span {
    color:yellow;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4rf3pmva/3/)

You can use `:hover` on an element in CSS which means when your mouse is hovering over that element, it will change.

To get something inside of it to move, you have just do `.firstElement:hover .childelement` and with this, when you hover over `.firstElement`, changes to `childelement` will be made.

---

In reply to the comment `How do I change the background color of .imgContent?`

```
.no-padding:hover .imgContent {
    background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following css
Note: choose the color of your choice

```
.no-padding:hover span {
    color: #00FF00; /*text Color to be changed*/
}

.no-padding:hover .imgContent {
    background-color:#CC00CC !important; /*Inner div background color*/
}
```